# Convert string to int with format

Tags: java

I have this number 3.445 and I need to convert it to int so I can write it to postgre database. This is my code:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.UK);
numberOfEmployees = (Integer) numberFormat.parse(numberOfEmployeesString);
```

NOTE: This number is three thousand four hundred and forty four.

Comment: 3.445 is not the number you're describing in words.

Comment: And what it gives you ?

Comment: A number doesn't have a format.  To retain the format, you can keep it as a String.

Comment: 3.445 in the UK locale is about 3 and a half. If you're intending to use a period as a thousands separator, you'll need a different locale that formats numbers in this way.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think you know what I'm trying to say. There's no need for editing. If you don't know how to answer it, just skip and try other ones.

Comment: @Faruk Take it easy, I'm trying to help. I might be misunderstood your question, just correct me. And when there's a need for an edit **I'll edit**.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Which part you can't understand? I have string "3.445" and I need to convert it to integer.

Comment: @Faruk Now I understand. It's not a crime to misunderstand things, that's why we ask and answer each other.

Comment: "3.445" is "three point four four five" and not "three thousand four hundres and forty for". It would be in German, but not in English. That's probably the source of the confusion here.

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be "three thousand four hundreds and forty four". That is problem. I know that problem is about format...

Comment: Then why do you specifically choose `Locale.UK` when you know it won't work with it? Choose `Locale.GERMANY` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  String bd = "3.445";///this is the string which you have 

  ////If you want the grouping separator to be a point, you can use an european locale:
  Number parse = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(java.util.Locale.GERMAN).parse(bd);

  int n=parse.intValue();/// this is the integer value for your string
```

Comment: OK, I know the answer now. Can you tell me why is this not working:
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
numberOfEmployees = (Integer) numberFormat.parse(numberOfEmployeesString);

Comment: because you will get exception said : `java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
int i = numberOfEmployees != null ? numberOfEmployees.intValue() : 0;
```

You might convert it to a String, remove the "." (which I first misread), then get the int value from the String with Integer.parseInt
However, this all depends if you can determine the value will always have that format.